# Как обратить условие в C# скрипте?

Tags: c#

Добрый день есть скрипт на игровом сервере, я не использую visual studio, а отлаживаю прямо на сервере встроенным компилятором. Смысл скрипта в том, что бы блокировать использование некоторых предметов пока не наступила определенная дата в переменной `DeniedInvtims`
то есть пока дата не наступила, то предметы указанные в `void OnGetClientMove`
списком `if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Torch") ?? false))`
Дело в том, что это список разрешенных предметов. То есть скрипт устроен так, что бы блокировать все предметы кроме тех что указаны в списке. Я долго думал, как обратить условие.
Пробовал убирать ! в `inv.activeItem?` в каждом условии предмета. что бы сделать таким образом список запрещенных предметов. Но как тогда указать скрипту, что бы он не блокировал все а только указанные?
Сам скрипт:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Oxide.Core;
using Oxide.Core.Libraries;
using RustExtended;
using UnityEngine;

namespace Oxide.Plugins
{
    [Info("Blockpredmet", "misvor", 1.0)]
    class Blockpredmet : RustLegacyPlugin
    {
        IInventoryItem item;
        private Core.Configuration.DynamicConfigFile DeniedInv;
        DateTime DeniedInvtims = new DateTime(2020, 07, 17, 03, 00, 00); //(Год,Месяц,День,Час,Минуты,Секунды)
        DateTime outputDateTimeValue;
        bool hasAccess(NetUser netuser, string permissionname)
        {
            if (netuser.CanAdmin()) return true;
            else if (permission.UserHasPermission(netuser.playerClient.userID.ToString(), "Admin"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            return permission.UserHasPermission(netuser.playerClient.userID.ToString(), permissionname);
        }
        void LoadData()
        {
            DeniedInv = Interface.GetMod().DataFileSystem.GetDatafile("Deniedinvconfig");
        }
        void SaveData()
        {
            Interface.GetMod().DataFileSystem.SaveDatafile("Deniedinvconfig");
        }       
        void OnGetClientMove(HumanController сontroller, Vector3 newPos)
        {
            DateTime CurTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (CurTime<=DeniedInvtims)
            {
                System.TimeSpan fulltime = DeniedInvtims.Subtract(CurTime);
                var netuser = сontroller.netUser;
                var inv = netuser.playerClient.rootControllable.idMain.GetComponent<Inventory>();
                //Разрешенные предметы
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Torch") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Rock") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Pipe") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Hatchet") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Bow") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Axe") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Revolver") ?? false))           
                //if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("M4") ?? false))       
                //if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("MP5A4") ?? false))
                //if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Shotgun") ?? false))  
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Pipe Shotgun") ?? false))
                //if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("P250") ?? false)) 
                //if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Bolt Action Rifle") ?? false))                    
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wall") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Pillar") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Foundation") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Doorway") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Window") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Stairs") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Ramp") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Ceiling") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Box") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Spike") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Shelter") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Bed") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Metal Door") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Large Wood Storage") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Furnace") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood Gate") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood Storage Box") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood Bariccade") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wooden Door") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood Gateway") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Repair Bench") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Workbench") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("HandCannon") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("9mm Pistol") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood Barricade") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Wood") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Fire") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("HandCannon") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Bag") ?? false))
                if (inv != null && (!inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name?.Contains("Bed") ?? false))
                {
                    if (!hasAccess(netuser, "Admin"))
                    {
                        var giveup = DatablockDictionary.GetByName(inv.activeItem.datablock.name);
                        int giveslot = inv.activeItem.slot;             
                        if (inv.GetItem(giveslot, out item))
                            {
                                var mod = item as IHeldItem;
                                int slot = giveslot;
                                string name = item.datablock.name.ToString();
                                int qty = Convert.ToInt32(item.uses);
                                if (qty == 0) return;
                                float condition = Convert.ToSingle(item.condition);
                                string modslots = "";
                                string mods = "";
                                if (mod != null)
                                {
                                    modslots = mod.totalModSlots.ToString();
                                    mods = mod.modFlags.ToString();
                                }
                                inv.RemoveItem(giveslot);
                                IInventoryItem itemmod;
                                AddItemToSlot(inv, name, slot, qty);
                                if (inv.GetItem(slot, out itemmod))
                                {
                                    itemmod.SetCondition(condition);
                                    if (Convert.ToInt32(modslots) != 0)
                                    {
                                        var m = itemmod as IHeldItem;
                                        m.SetTotalModSlotCount(Convert.ToInt32(modslots));
                                    }
                                }
                                    string giveupe=giveup.ToString();
                                    int dotIndex = giveupe.IndexOfAny(new char[]{ '('});
                                    if (dotIndex >= 0)
                                    {
                                        giveupe = giveupe.Substring(0, dotIndex);
                                        rust.SendChatMessage(netuser, "Блок", string.Format(" Запрещенно использовать " + giveupe + " еще " +Convert.ToInt32(fulltime.TotalMinutes)+ " минут"));
                                    }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        void AddItemToSlot(Inventory inv, string name, int slot, int amount)
        {
            ItemDataBlock byName = DatablockDictionary.GetByName(name);
            if (byName != null)
            {
                Inventory.Slot.Kind belt = Inventory.Slot.Kind.Default;
                if ((slot > 0x1d) && (slot < 0x24))
                {
                    belt = Inventory.Slot.Kind.Belt;
                }
                else if ((slot >= 0x24) && (slot < 40))
                {
                    belt = Inventory.Slot.Kind.Armor;
                }
                inv.AddItemSomehow(byName, new Inventory.Slot.Kind?(belt), slot, amount);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

И можно ли как то указать несколько дат и несколько списков блокирующих предметов?
например, что бы одни предметы блокировались до одной даты, а другие уже до другой даты?

Comment: Это что за ужасный список, не уж то нельзя было сделать коллекцию и все прописать динамически? Скажем `var whiteList = new[] { "Ramp", "Ceiling" };` и дальше `if (whiteList.Contains(inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name)) /* предмет в белом списке */` и смотрите как я вам уже сократил код и сделал его более читаемым и понятным, всего одним изменением!

Comment: и действительно, сейчас попробую переделать.
я не программист c#, да и вообще не программист, немного понимаю азы, поэтому и занимаюсь этим делом.
а скажите как мне инвентировать? или сделать реверс в этом скрипте?
что бы был не белый список а черный, что бы указать предметы которые нужно блокировать, а не блокировать все и разрешать лишь конкретные.

Comment: я преобразовал, вбил список в коллекцию, но теперь не срабатывает скрипт((

Comment: Сделал так `if (inv != null && (whiteList.Contains((inv.activeItem?.datablock?.name) ?? false)))` но теперь в консоли получаю:  Error while compiling Blockpredmet.cs(47,35): error CS0411: The type arguments for method `Oxide.ExtensionMethods.Contains<T>(this T[], T)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly

Comment: `что бы был не белый список а черный` - ну для этого просто меняйте как вам надо условие `if (список.Содержит()) { делаем с тем предметом, что надо }` или `if (!список.Содержит()){ Делаем что надо с тем, что не находится в списке }`, этого я думаю вам достаточно. `не срабатывает скрипт` - мне не о чем не говорит. `в консоли получаю` - посмотрите на тип, что за `Oxide.ExtensionMethods`? Вы уверены, что вызываете нужный метод поиска? И почему `?? false`? Это означает "Если объект слева NULL, то выдать false. У вас поиск по строке, какой false?? Это лишнее...

Comment: в таком виде как он есть, он работает.
исходников нет, скрипты подключаю как плагины

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, что `inv.activeItem.datablock.name` это `string`, то получается такая функция:

```cs
private bool ActiveItemContains(Inventory inventory, string[] items)
{
    if (inventory?.activeItem?.datablock?.name is string itemName && itemName?.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (string item in items)
        {
            if (itemName.Contains(item)) return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Только учтите, что `string.Contains()` возвращает `true`, если в ней содержится фрагмент, другими словами, если у вас в списке уже есть `Wood`, то нет никакого смысла туда добавлять `Wooden Door`, `Wood Gateway`, и т.д. Либо следует праверять на точное соответствие:

```cs
if (itemName.Equals(item)) return true;
```

или так

```cs
if (itemName == item) return true;
```

---

А использовать можно вот так:

```cs
string[] itemsList = new string[]
{
    "Torch", "Rock", "Pipe", "Hatchet", "Bow", "Axe", "Revolver",
    // "M4", "MP5A4", "Shotgun", 
    "Pipe Shotgun",
    // "P250", "Bolt Action Rifle",
    "Wall", "Pillar", "Foundation", "Doorway", "Window", "Stairs",
    "Ramp", "Ceiling", "Box", "Spike", "Shelter", "Bed",
    "Metal Door", "Large Wood Storage", "Furnace", "Wood Gate", "Wood Storage Box", "Wood Bariccade",
    "Wooden Door", "Wood Gateway", "Repair Bench", "Workbench", "HandCannon", "9mm Pistol",
    "Wood Barricade", "Wood", "Fire", "HandCannon", "Bag", "Bed"
};

if (ActiveItemContains(inv, itemsList))
{
    ...
}
```

Ну и чтобы обратить условие, можно просто воткнуть в него `!`

```cs
if (!ActiveItemContains(inv, itemsList))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: попробую ваш вариант, отпишусь.

Comment: ошибка в консоли: [Error] Error while compiling Blockpredmet.cs(59,28): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `['

Comment: @karakym да блин, забываю про древний компилятор, исправил код `string[] itemsList = new string[]`